# Is it ok to run fsck intead of e2fsck for a read only badblocks correction?

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, fsck, badblocks

I have a hard drive with a failing block that points to inode 8 of the first partition, this falls in exactly on the journal. So I tried to run e2fsck -cpvk but the problem is that i forgot to write e2 and instead run fsck with the same commands, like fsck -cpvk /dev/sdd1 , I hope that this are equivalent, however I think that for an ext4 partition fsck should run fsck.ext4 instead of e2fsck, so I still hope they are all the same.

Also I read that I should rewrite the entire journal to the partition,  but I considered more safe to mark the bad blocks first. Am I'm doing well or my safety consideritions and mistype are scrpapping all?

Edit: I somehow already figured that they are luckly the same (if everything on the system and filesystem is between safe parameters -like nothing wild coming in-, which luckly is). Now it results that the inode 8 is multiply claimed by "other files", coming from fsck those "files" should be some other parts of the journal, but how can I tell? now the question is weather to remake the journal on that partition or not.

fsck said that I should to run it again MANUALLY (whithout -a or -p options), what means I've been left outside for the elements.

So should I face the elements or wish good luck at rewritteing the journal?

I don't know what option would be worse, luckly I already have an image of that partition done bt ddrescue.

Comment: `fsck.ext4` is a link to `e2fsck`

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

"
*In actuality, fsck is simply a front-end for the various filesystem checkers (fsck.fstype) available under Linux. The filesystem-specific checker
is searched for in the PATH environment variable. If the PATH is undefined then fallback to /sbin.
Please see the filesystem-specific checker manual pages for further details.*
"

It's automatically going to run the right fsck for whatever file system exists on the partition you've indicated.

Comment: @span I somehow already figured it out. Now it results that the inode 8 is multiply claimed by "other files", coming from fsck those "files" should be some other parts of the journal, no the question is weather to remake the journal on that partition or not.

fsck said that I should to run it again MANUALLY (whithout -a or -p options), what means I've been left outside for the elements.

I don't know what option would be wose, luck I already have an image of that partition done bt ddrescue.